# Excel Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to loop through all sheets in a spreadsheet and clear the contents of cells A4 to the end of the sheet.

I have it working if the spreadsheet only contains 1 sheet.
If it contains more than 1 sheet, it fails when trying to clear the contents on sheet 2.

The line in error is `.Range("A4", Range("A4").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).ClearContents`

When it hits that line, I get the error 'Excel Application-defined or object-defined error'

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
    Set book = Workbooks.Open("folder-containing-excel-spreadsheets")
    For Each Sheet In book.Sheets
        With Sheet
            .Range("A4", Range("A4").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).ClearContents
        End With
    Next
    book.Save
    book.Close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
.Range("A4", Range("A4").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).ClearContents
```

to

```
.Range("A4", .Range("A4").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).ClearContents
```

You've missed `.` before `Range("A4").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)` and so, `Range("A4").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)` always tries to find last cell in first sheet

Comment: Well spotted. The missing dot, I mean.

Comment: Can't believe I fell for the old missing dot routine :) Thanks for spotting!